# Azure policy- Check if initiative exists

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, policy, azureportal

I'm new to Azure policy and Powershell and I'm wondering if there's a way to check if:

- an initiative exist, then do nothing.
- if it doesn't exist, create it.

Any tip that can guide me to the solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A policy initiative (which is also called a policy set), can be retrieved in Powershell's Az module with:

```
Get-AzPolicySetDefinition | Select -Expand Properties
```

or in the AZ CLI with:

```
az policy set-definition list | ConvertFrom-Json
```